# Dragstop on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, drag

Im using JQuery for recognizing dragstart and dragstop.
The dragstart event is working perfectly but the dragstop event doesn't.
Here is the code i wrote-

```js
$('img').on('dragstart', function (event) {
 $(function() {        
            $("#toolbar").animate({width:'toggle'},0);      
  });
  
});
$('img').on('dragstop', function (event) {
  alert("hi"); 
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dragend` event! **Fired when a drag operation is being *ended***

Refer [**`HTML Drag and Drop API`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) for all the events.

```js
$('#image').on('dragstart', function(event) {
  console.log('dragstart');
});
$('#image').on('dragend', function(event) {
  console.log('dragend');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.repeatsoftware.com/Help/img3C.gif" id="image" height="100px" width="100px" />
```